# Issues with Canon LBP6000 printer driver

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I've been trying to install Canon's LBP6000 printer in Ubuntu 13.04 with no success. I downloaded the driver from Canon's website and tried various solutions across the web, including the radu script (http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu).

All the solutions I've found are at least a year old and deal with an older driver (2.40 instead of 2.60) and version of Ubuntu.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1):

To make my LBP6020 (the renewed version if LBP6000 but just identical really) to work correctly i had to perform the following steps

1. disable **usblp** printer auto recognition in `/lib/udev/rules.d/70-printers.rules`. my file now looks like (note 4th line):

   ```
   # Low-level USB device add trigger
   ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="07", ATTR{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01", TAG+="udev-configure-printer", RUN+="udev-configure-printer add %p"
   # usblp device add trigger (needed when usblp is already loaded)
   #ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="lp*", TAG+="udev-configure-printer", RUN+="udev-configure-printer add %p"

   # Low-level USB device remove trigger
   ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="*:0701*:*", RUN+="udev-configure-printer remove %p"
   ```

   *without this step there is always an auto-discovered copy of LBP6020 which is not working, maybe there is a way to make this auto-discovered printer work, but i didn't try this*
2. download from Canon and install Linux driver (2 deb packages from archive) - i installed 2.60
3. create a rule to *restart ccpd* when the printer is connected. i created `/etc/udev/rules.d/85-canon-capt.rules` with the contents:

   ```
   KERNEL=="lp[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="0000B1D0DLkI", ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="canonLBP6020", RUN+="/bin/bash -c '/etc/init.d/ccpd stop && /bin/sleep 5 && /etc/init.d/ccpd start'"
   ```

   be sure to change the serial number (the value of `ATTRS{serial}`) to yours, which can be obtained by `lsusb -d 04a9: -v | grep iSerial`. this script also creates a static symlink `/dev/canonLBP6020` which is useful in case you have multiple `/dev/usblp*` devices. i used this symlink in next step.
4. create a printer using command line

   ```
   lpadmin -p LBP6020 -m CNCUPSLBP6020CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59687 -E
   sudo ccpdadmin -p LBP6020 -o /dev/canonLBP6020
   ```
5. restart `cups` and `ccpd` or restart the system.

After connecting the printer to usb each time wait 5 seconds before starting using it. This is the time that is needed to restart ccpd daemon by the rule in step 3 (note `sleep 5` there, unfortunately the `/etc/init.d/ccpd restart` doesn't work correctly for me, but you can try it yourself).